# Extract dataURL from Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that aims to create a dataURL of a file using the FileReader. Considering this example.

```
toDataURL(url, callback){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('get', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(){
    var fr = new FileReader();
    var test = fr.onload = function(){
      callback(this.result);
    };

    fr.readAsDataURL(xhr.response); // async call
  };

  xhr.send();
}
```

I want to extract the variable `this.result` in the inline function as a return variable. It has not acces from other function. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly, what you want to do is return a value from an async function, you can do this with Promises, and optionally async/await.

Check this out:

```js
function toDataURL(url, callback) {
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var fr = new FileReader();
      var test = fr.onload = function() {
        resolve(this.result)
        callback(this.result);
      };

      fr.readAsDataURL(xhr.response); // async call
    };
    
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      reject('Error);
    }

    xhr.send();
  });
}

const result = await toDataURL('some url');

// or

toDataURL('some url').then((result) => {
  // do something with the result
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `Promise`, like this:

```js
toDataURL(url){
  var promise = new Promise(function (extract) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function(){
      var fr = new FileReader();
      var test = fr.onload = function(){
        extract(this.result);
      };

      fr.readAsDataURL(xhr.response); // async call
    };

    xhr.send();
  });

  return promise;
}

(async function () {
  var result = await toDataURL('/someurl');

  console.log(result);
}());
```

Inside the `toDataURL` function, we create a promise. When returning the result, we just need to put it inside `extract` method.

Then, we create an asynchronous function to use `await` keyword to get the result directly.

Comment: I have an other questio. For Typescrippt, how can I change the global variable in the promise function?